# Mobile CSS does not load from link, but loads from style tag

Tags: html, css, mobile

The CSS does not load on mobile if I load the CSS using this code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" id="style-theme-css" href="http://mywebsite/wp-content/themes/agile/style.css?ver=4.3.1" type="text/css" media="all">
```

It does load when I copy the contents of the CSS file into a `<style>` tag.

It works on desktops.

**Addtional information**

I am testing in Chrome.

I see that Chrome adds this user agent stylesheet:

```
link {
    display: none;
}
```

I tried to turn it off, but still no style.

Comment: Just to check, you do have a tld after your website name? for example mywebsite.com/wp.. and not just mywebsite/wp..

Comment: it doesnt look like a css file that you are loading

Comment: Generally wordpress doesn't store the css in that path. If you open that link in browser does it show the style sheet?

Comment: broser says http://mywebsite/wp-content/themes/agile/style.css?ver=4.3.1 is not available.. check the css file and load it

Comment: Serious answers please. `mywebsite` should of course be replaced by my website. This is not the official URL. And yes, it does load. It works on a desktop. It is a CSS file with cache busting enabled. And yes, I have a top level domain.

Comment: @Z0q These are serious answers, if you give us pseudo code make sure it acts like the real thing. We cannot verify the file is accessible, or that the css within it is valid without you giving us that information. At this point we are guessing.